# How do you run a pm2 cron job without caring if a process it kicks off has started or not?

Tags: javascript, cron, pm2

To explain my situation. I have a pm2 cron script that I run using:

```
pm2 start clear-redis-state-cron.js -n clearState --cron '0 0/1 * 1/1 * *'
```

This runs the js script called `clear-redis-state-cron.js` just fine.

The role of this script is to stop process `p1` and process `p2`. It then runs a lua redis script that clears some keys from the database. This all works fine but I've put it here for brevity.

```
var crs = require('./clear-redis-state'),
    pm2 = require('pm2');

pm2.connect(function(err) {
    pm2.stop('component1');
    pm2.stop('component2');

    crs.clear();

    pm2.restart(__dirname + '/../../node_modules/component1/index.js', { name: 'c1' }, function (err, proc) {
        if (err) throw new Error('err');
    });

    pm2.restart(__dirname + '/../../node_modules/component2/index.js', { name: 'c2' }, function (err, proc) {
        if (err) throw new Error('err');
    });
});
```

It runs a `clear()` js function which is defined here:

```
var config = require('common/lib/config'),
    log = require('common/lib/logger'),
    redis = require('common/lib/redis'),
    ScriptTo = require('redis-scripto');

exports.clear = function() {
    log.init();

    if (!config.isSet()) {
        // Use local config
        var configPath = require('path').join(__dirname, '../../app/config');
        config.load(configPath);
    }

    redis.init(config.get('redis'));

    var scriptManager = new ScriptTo(redis.getClient());
    scriptManager.loadFromDir(__dirname + '/scripts');

    scriptManager.run('clear-state', [], [], function(err, results) {
        logError(err);
        console.log('results:', results);
    });

    function logError(err) {
        if (err !== null) {
            console.log('Error loading lua script merge-keys: ', err);
        }
    };
}
```

I have no problems with that. However, it seems to crash on start. Let's say I already have pm2 running two processes component1 and component2 called p1 and p2 respectively. Why would I get the following error when starting the cron when I run it with `--no-daemon`?

```
... clear-redis-state-cron.js had too many unstable restarts (15). Stopped. "errored"
```

My hunch is that either the process is starting up shutting down incorrectly and is in the wrong state as a result so when it tries to close it it's already closed, but because pm2 assumes something went wrong the cron process is stopped.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Edit: I tried promisifying my shutdown pm2 logic like so:

```
pm2.connect(function(err) {

    Promise.resolve(ops.stop('component1'))
       .then(ops.stop('component2'))
       .then(ops.clear)
       .then(ops.restart(__dirname + '/../../node_modules/component1/index.js', { name: 'component1' }))
       .then(ops.restart(__dirname + '/../../node_modules/component2/index.js', { name: 'component2' }))
       .catch(logFailureToStop);
});

var logFailureToStop = function (err) {
    console.log('Failed to stop ', err);
};
```

With following result after stopping processes that are running:

```
$ pm2 list
┌───────────┬────┬──────┬───────┬─────────┬───────────┬────────┬─────────────┬──────────┐
│ App name  │ id │ mode │ PID   │ status  │ restarted │ uptime │      memory │ watching │
├───────────┼────┼──────┼───────┼─────────┼───────────┼────────┼─────────────┼──────────┤
│ component2│ 0  │ fork │ 0     │ stopped │        17 │ 0      │      0 B    │ disabled │
│ component1│ 1  │ fork │ 18769 │ online  │        31 │ 19s    │ 30.539 MB   │ disabled │
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to resolve this issue in the end.

The issue was caused because I had an on handler event listening into SIGTERM. Apparently these interfere with PM2 so you need to instead use the gracefulStop/gracefulRestart commands.

See: https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/issues/304